# Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors with Variational Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a custom Variational Autoencoder. The code is shown below

```
image = Input(shape = (X_train.shape[1]))
label = Input(shape = (Y_train.shape[1]))

inputs = Concatenate()([image, label])

x = Dense(625, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
x = Reshape((25,25,1))(x)

x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (5,5), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (5,5), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (3,3), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (3,3), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

encoder_out = Flatten()(x)

mu = Dense(latent_size, activation ='linear')(encoder_out)
sigma = Dense(latent_size, activation = 'linear')(encoder_out)

def sampling(args):
    mu, sigma = args
    eps = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_size), mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return mu + K.exp(sigma / 2) * eps

latent_space = Lambda(sampling, output_shape = (latent_size, ))([mu, sigma])

decoder_latent = Input(shape = (latent_size, ))
decoder_c = Input(shape = (c_space, ))

x = Concatenate()([decoder_latent, decoder_c])

x = Dense(288)(x)
x = Reshape((6,6,8))(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(x)
x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (3,3), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(x)
x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (3,3), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(x)
x = LocallyConnected2D(8, (5,5), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(x)
x = LocallyConnected2D(8,(5,5), padding = 'valid')(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

x = LocallyConnected2D(1,(4,4), padding = 'valid')(x)
decoder_out = Activation('relu')(x)
```

The loss function I defined as

```
def DFC_loss(x_in, x_out):
    kl_loss = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma, axis=1)
    return K.mean(perceptual_loss(x_in, x_out) + kl_loss)

def perceptual_loss(x_in, x_out):
    
    x_in = K.reshape(x_in, shape=(batch_size, 25,25,1))
    x_out = K.reshape(x_out, shape=(batch_size, 25,25,1))
    
    conv_outputs = [classifier.get_layer(l).output for l in selected_layers]
    
    activation = Model(classifier.input, conv_outputs)

    h1_list = activation(x_in)
    h2_list = activation(x_out)
    
    rc_loss = 0.0
    
    for h1, h2, weight in zip(h1_list, h2_list, [1.0, 1.0]):
        h1 = K.batch_flatten(h1)
        h2 = K.batch_flatten(h2)
        rc_loss = rc_loss + weight * K.sum(K.square(h1 - h2), axis=-1)
    
    return rc_loss

CVAE.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = DFC_loss, metrics = [perceptual_loss])
```

Whenever I run the code below

```
CVAE_hist = CVAE.fit([X_train,Y_train], X_train, verbose = 1, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=n_epochs, validation_data = ([X_test, Y_test], X_test))
```

I get two errors

```
An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: dense_2_1/Identity:0
```

and

```
Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'dense_2_1/Identity:0' shape=(None, 6) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_1_1/Identity:0' shape=(None, 6) dtype=float32>]
```

What was interesting is whenever I set the loss function as the perceptual loss alone without the Kl divergence loss, my code did not receive an error. There are many implementations of the KL divergence loss for the Variational Autoencoder but I do not know why it did not work with this specific implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having the same problem for a long time, but managed to figure it out.
The problem is that TF only accepts loss functions which accept `(input, output)` parameters which are then compared. However, you are computing your (kl_)loss using also `mu` and `sigma`, which are basically dense layers. Until tensorflow v2.1 it magically knew what these parameters were and knew how to include/manipulate them, but from then on, you have to be more careful. After reading [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_add_loss_method) (EDIT: also scroll to the bottom of the page for the complete VAE example) I propose these changes to your code:

**1. When compiling your model, only define `perceptual_loss` as a loss:**

`CVAE.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = perceptual_loss, metrics = [perceptual_loss])`

**2. Change `sampling` function into a class, and under `call` method, add your `kl_loss`**, something like

```
class Sampling(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sampling, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        _, sigma_shape = input_shape
        self.sigma_shape = (sigma_shape[-1], )

    def call(self, inputs):
        mu, sigma = inputs

        # Add loss
        kl_loss = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma, axis=1)
        self.add_loss(K.mean(kl_loss))
        
        # Return sampling as before
        eps = K.random_normal(self.sigma_shape, mean=0., stddev=1.)
        return mu + K.exp(sigma / 2) * eps
```

Make sure you only add `kl_loss` not `DFC_loss` , so that you don't count `perceptual_loss` twice.

**3. Use `Sampling` class as a latent layer**

`latent_space = Sampling()([mu, sigma])`

This is my first answer, hope it helps!

P.S. Maybe you can also try moving both losses in the Sampling class via `add_loss` command and then compile without any `loss` parameter.